# Java applet tag for IE: require java 6, install java 8

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet

I'm using java applet on my site. I want to provide correct applet tags which will work in modern browsers and in old IE versions (8+). As far as I understand, modern browsers use `<embed>` tag and `<object>` tag provides best experience for Internet Explorer. Internet Explorer even performs automatically silent Java installation, if user does not have installed Java without browser restart. That's very nice.

Now the problem is, most of the documentation regarding `<object>` tag is outdated. My applet compiles with Java 1.6 and works fine with it, but obviously I want users to install the latest Java. I can't find official documentation about silent installation for Java 8. If I specify `classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA"`, probably that will install Java 1.6 and that's bad. I've found some urls for downloading `.cab` files and there are no urls for Java 8. Did Oracle remove that convenient method for Java 8?

What is the best approach to use for embedding Java Applets with modern Java with Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Java Rich Internet Applications Deployment Advice](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html) for details of the deployment toolkit script.  It should write whatever applet tags are recommended for that user agent.

> If I specify `classid="clsid:CAFEEFAC-0016-0000-FFFF-ABCDEFFEDCBA"`, probably that will install Java 1.6..

Not anymore.  Oracle has dropped support for loading/using an older JRE.  Apparently they have become sick of supporting older JREs with potential security bugs.